# How to solve the "The following module is missing from the file system" error?

Tags: 8

I am getting the following error in a Drupal 8 site.

> The following module is missing from the file system

It looks as if a custom module was installed and deleted without uninstalling it.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you using the configuration management in the site?

Comment: Yes I am using that

Comment: Some advance with the problem? I want to know at the end how do you solve the problem, this can arrive me too in any project.

Comment: In Drupal 8.7.3 I am getting "following module is missing from the file system: php in drupal_get_filename()" but when I try install the php module I get an error about it already existing in core. The error is preventing me from uninstalling anything. Yesterday I upgraded to 8.7.3 and today to 8.5.3 and cannot shake the error. Cache has been cleared each time and all modules that I know about have been restored. I see notes about Drush but how to install it on 8.7.3?

Answer (score 25):

Drush 9

```
drush cdel core.extension module.MYMODULE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It might be helpful to add a bit more explanation about config:delete and maybe use config:delete rather than the cryptic cdel. I think this also works for Drush 10.

Comment: Worked for me on a Drupal 9 instance.

Comment: This actually worked for me on a drupal 8.8 migration. Ty!

Comment: worked for me on d Drupal 10 instance!

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you have deleted an unimportant custom module which doesn't need any uninstall routine to be triggered, you can use the following Drush command.

- Drupal 7

  ```
  drush sql-query "DELETE from system where type = 'module' AND name = 'MYMODULE';"
  ```
- Drupal 8

  ```
  drush sql-query "DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='MYMODULE';"
  ```

---

See [How to fix "The following module is missing from the file system..." warning messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215) for more info and alternatives.

Comment: I tried few times and this for D8 doesnt work at least for d8.7. I would recommend solution below with generating dummy module and then uinstalling.

Comment: The Drupal 8 command worked for me for a Drupal 9.3.9 upgrade from 8.

Answer (score 14):

If you have Drupal Console then a quick way to fix this is to generate a module with the same machine name, then uninstall it.

```
$ drupal generate:module
```

Then type the machine name at the appropriate prompt and accepts defaults for everything else.

```
$ drush pm-uninstall
```

Then you can delete the newly generated module from the file system and continue with your day.

(NB you may find need to keep that generated module, else the error will return. In that case, if you need to install a contrib module with the same name, remove the generated module after adding the contrib module. Then clear the cache.)

Comment: This was the simplest option after the SQL query above wouldn't work.

Comment: It helped to resolve my error for module not found.

Comment: If anyone needs help installing Drupal Console, I found [this page](https://www.drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2017/03/installing-drupal-console-existing-drupal-8-project) helpful. Bear in mind, you'll want to install the **Drupal Console Launcher** globally, AND the **Drupal Console** locally (in the project root of your Drupal install).

Answer (score 5):

The way I fixed it was by using drush and composer. Get the module with require, install and uninstall with drush then remove with composer.

```
composer require drupal/missing_module
drush en missing_module
drush pmu missing_module
composer remove drupal/missing_module
```

**!** The step with `drush en` probably is not nessesary

Answer (score 4):

Now with the Configuration Management module the modules configuration is stored in the core.extension.yml file.

Go to edit the file and try to find the missing module from the filesystem then delete the line and import the config (`drush cim`).

If this not works but you has found the module, then create the module again (just the folder and a valid .info.yml file) and run again the `drush cim` command. This will uninstall the module.

Comment: This works, but the *correct* way is to restore the module and uninstall it. If that module provides schemas, configuration or so, it will remain in the system and you will have to clean it up manually otherwise.

Comment: @Berdir if you can't find the custom module, we can do another thing?

Comment: Not really, then you need to do it manually as suggested above with drush cedit or import/export in the core.extension file.

Answer (score -1):

if you know exactely what you're doing and can't use a cleaner method from https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/troubleshooting-database-updates

here is a suggestion :

```
drush php:eval '\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("core.extension")->clear("module.MY_MODULE_THAT_BREAKS_THINGS")->save(TRUE);'
drush cr
```

Comment: If you're going to use drush,  why do this instead of config:delete?