# How can I remove a theme that is no longer in core?

Tags: 8

Drush/Drupal 8 is throwing errors because a theme is 'enabled' that is 'missing'. The theme is/was part of core (`test_stable`), and I'm having difficulty getting it to uninstall.

I understand that the theme code needs to be there in order to uninstall, but this being core makes that difficult. I can manually place the module there locally, but would need to create a patch to actually have it installed (and then uninstalled) on the remote environments via composer.

The "Module Missing Message Fixer" module addresses this scenario with modules, but not themes.

I'm pretty sure enabling this theme in the first place was an accident. I'm hoping someone can help me determine if there is a way to do this w/out creating a patch that installs this old theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "The following module is missing from the file system" error?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/how-to-solve-the-the-following-module-is-missing-from-the-file-system-error)

Comment: It is helpful information.  Thanks.  Given the way things are deployed, the answer by @miststudent2011 was a good fit.

Comment: @MichaelBopp on a side not have you ran all the pending updates ?
It seems test_stable theme is removed after Drual 8.7.x as that file is not present in latest versions.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21tests%21themes%21test_stable%21test_stable.theme/8.7.x
Before proceeding with m suggestion below run `drush updbst` and check for pending updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a theme calling it *test_stable*. Then, you clear the cache with `drush cr` and uninstall the theme with `drush theme:uninstall test_stable`. It will solve your problem.

You don't need to create the whole theme; the *test_stable.info.yml* file is sufficient for Drupal to recognize the theme as present.

As the *test_stable* theme has been removed from Drupal after Drupal 8.7.x, and that file isn't present in latest versions, before proceeding with what I suggested, I would run `drush updbst` and check for pending updates.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue :

> The base theme stable cannot be uninstalled, because theme classy
> depends on it.

I solved it without install a fake theme. I simply executed these 2 Drush Commands :

```
drush theme-uninstall classy

drush theme-uninstall stable
```